# Multilabel classification with xgboost and temporal dynamic

Tags: classification, predictive-models, python, boosting

In my training I have 10 months of data and the task is predict for next month top N products for each users. As I see popularity of each product have a significant trend. It means that if we teach a model on the first month prediction for 10 month will contain mistake. How include this effect into model? Now I use xgboost multiclass classification ('multi:softprob'), then sort products by predicted probabilities and get top N.